# How to make onesignal plugin send notification only to mobile app?

Tags: php, wordpress, ionic-framework, web-applications, onesignal

I have an ionic android app connected to OneSignal, and WordPress with which I make posts through my WordPress site. I installed the OneSignal plugin and put the customised code provided by Onesignal to send notification only to the mobile app and not to the browser. However, when I click the notification it takes me to the web instead of the app.

The below code is for sending notification only to mobile app. When I use this code I get notification but it takes me to web. The code is pasted below from [their documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/wordpress#section-sending-notifications-only-to-mobile-apps-not-browsers-).

```
<?php
function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
    $fields['isAndroid'] = true;
    $fields['isIos'] = true;
    $fields['isAnyWeb'] = false;
    $fields['isChrome'] = false;
    $fields['data'] = array(
        "myappurl" => $fields['url']
    );
    /* Unset the URL to prevent opening the browser when the notification is clicked */
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: People probably won't read code on external sources. Add the relevant parts to your post, please.

Comment: Improved english, formatting, added php tag

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?php
add_filter('onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_send_notification_filter', 10, 4);

function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{

    $fields = $fields;
    $fields['isAndroid'] = true;
    $fields['isIos'] = true;
    $fields['isAnyWeb'] = false;
    $fields['isWP'] = false;
    $fields['isAdm'] = false;
    $fields['isChrome'] = false;
    $fields['data'] = array(
        "myappurl" => $fields['url']
    );
        /* Unset the URL to prevent opening the browser when the notification is clicked */
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
```